# Школа анализа данных Яндекса

Tags: математика

На страничке ШАД есть [пример](http://download.yandex.ru/company/shad/exam.pdf) задания письменного экзамена. Прочитав его и подумав немного я понял, что полностью я могу только 2 номер решить и кое как прикинул решение 5 и 1 задач, но все остальное вообще по нулям. Кака я понял, остальные хадачи больше по математике, какие есть курсы, книги, которе помогут мне подтянуть знания по матиматике на должный уровень ?

P.S. очень хочется попробовать свои силы и попытаться поступить в ШАД.

Comment: Классные задачи, есть над чем голову поломать...     
Не думаю ,что есть какая либо определенная литература, нацеленная на подготовку к экзамену. Думаю, стоит просто порешывать такие задачи.   
P.S. если ты вдруг не поступаешь в ШАД, то становишься "вольным слушателем", которые спустя год упешного обучения, зачисляются в число ШАДовцев

Comment: А вообще пошли сюда вместе решать:   
http://math.hashcode.ru/

Comment: хмм не знал про "вольного слушателя", то есть, как я понял, лекции я посещать смогу или все же нет ? Да я не то, чтобы литературу какую ту хотел чисто для экзамена, просто например задача №4 

"Какую наибольшую дисперсию может иметь случайная величина, принимающая значения в отрезке от 0 до 1?"

очевидно же, что это чистая математика. Я и зочу как то подтянуть мат часть.

Comment: подобные вопросы относятся к другому форуму, ссылку я уже дал.    
Что касается матчасти, то тут дело такое - каждая задача затрагивает определенную область - осталось лишь поискать литературу, задачи на каждую из областей        
Могу дать тебе мыло того, кто занимается приемом в шад, поговоришь с ним лично

Comment: буду очень Вам благодарен, если дадите мне его почту.

Comment: сам понимаешь, что такое в приват кидать нужно... скайп?

Comment: скайп: jetuuuu
ну или на почту, galnikrom@gmail.com

Comment: Судя по этим задачам, математика там будет сложная и с большим охватом(но не хардкорная, нет).  
Я сам олимпиадник по математике(даже немного успешный). И могу сказать, что учить/прорешивать, возможно, придётся долго и много.  
Тест: http://yadi.sk/d/Jrl25dZN3KYMd(задания закл. этапа Всеросса по матем.)